# get p tag to line up with header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys so I am creating a simple `fa icon` and I want the heading of one `p` tag to line up with anther one, however for some reason I can't seem to get it to line up. I would like all the text below to line up with the title right below. So to be in the same line as title, not below the picture.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="section1">
   <div class="container" id="section1">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-5">
            <ul class="get_in">
            <li>
              <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
              <p>Title</p>
               <p>Web DevelopmentWeb DevelopmentWeb DevelopmentDevelopmentWeb DevelopmenDevelopmentWeb Developmen</p>
            </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.section1 .get_in li i {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #373432;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 33px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    font-size:34px;
}

.get_in p {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

i {
  margin-right:6px;
}

.get_in li i:hover {
    background: #434343;
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/y7kptvf3/)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your CSS:

```
li {
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `<p>'s` display from `display: inline-block;` to `display: inline;` will move it up onto the same line:

```
.get_in p {
display: inline;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

However, as the second `<p>` content is quite long it is dropping down onto two spread out lines because of the icon circle. Perhaps try moving the `<i>` out of the `<ul>` and adding a `float: left;`